# how to separate buttons in html table

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to add buttons at the front of each row, but only the one in the first row would follow my setColor() function.

```
while(($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))&&($cnt<5)){
          if($row['type']=='0') {
              $cal+=$row['kcal'];
              $price+=$row['price'];
              if(($cal<=($_SESSION['calorie'])/3)){
                  echo"<tr>
                  <td>
                      <form>
                      <input type='button' value='+' onclick='setColor()' id='btn'>
                      </form></td>
                      <td>".$row['product']."</td>
                      <td>".$cal."</td>
                      <td>".$price."</td>
                      </tr>";
                  $cnt+=1;
              }
          $price=0;
          $cal=0;}
      }
```

here is the setColor JS function code

```
<script>
function setColor(){
    var count=1;
    if (count == 0){
        document.getElementById('btn').style.color = "gray";
        count=1;        
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('btn').style.color = "orange";
        count=0;
    }
    count=0
}

</script>
```

How can I separate them while keeping the while loop? Thanks.

Comment: This is a PHP issue or JS? Is the issue with generating the HTML or execution of `setColor()` function?

Comment: You're using an `id=btn`. html `id` fields are ment to unique, there should only ever exist 1 single item with any particular `id` value. you should probably lose the `id=` and use a class instead here (like `class="setcolorbutton"`), and then update your javascript and css to use `.setcolorbutton` instead of `#btn` aswell.

Comment: Please post the setcolor JS function code too

Comment: @user3783243 generating the HTML

Comment: This is a JS/HTML issue. The PHP is correct but you're using invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let the system know which button you want to change on clicking the button , one of the methods is to use a unique button ID.

Hence simply change to

```
$index=0;

while(($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))&&($cnt<5)){
          if($row['type']=='0') {
              $cal+=$row['kcal'];
              $price+=$row['price'];
              if(($cal<=($_SESSION['calorie'])/3)){
                  echo"<tr>
                  <td>
                      <form>
                      <input type='button' value='+' onclick='setColor(". $index . ")' id='btn". $index . "'>
                      </form></td>
                      <td>".$row['product']."</td>
                      <td>".$cal."</td>
                      <td>".$price."</td>
                      </tr>";
                  $cnt+=1;
              }
          $price=0;
          $cal=0;}
$index++;
      }
```

and use the following JS

```
<script>
function setColor(var1){
    var count=1;
    if (count == 0){
        document.getElementById('btn'+var1).style.color = "gray";
        count=1;        
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('btn'+var1).style.color = "orange";
        count=0;
    }
    count=0
}

</script>
```

For the JS code, I do not know what is the purpose of the "count", so you may wish to amend the code to suit your need.